# How to create inheritance based serialization mechanism?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, inheritance, serialization

I whould like to creat a serialization mechanism, to work on a variety of entities, all of which are based 
on a few base-classes.
Now I want to work with DataContractSerializer, so I need to mark all my classes with [DataContract].
but I dont want to do that because that is a big room for error for other members of my team. instead I want to place a singel attribute on my base-class(es), and not to worry about every calss I add.

I would actually prefer to inherit from [DataContract], should I ever wish to change the mechanism I will need to change only my inheriting attribute and not all my classes (the same goes for the [DataMember]).
Now the problem is that DataContractAttribute is a seald class.

I thought up 3 solution, but i dont know how to implement any of them...

**First**, I heard a rommer that there is a way to inherit from a seald class, that will be greate and save me a 
       lot of fuzz.

**Second**, I know that with reflection it's possible to change a class in runtime and re-compile back to runtime,
        so I thought to create my on attribute and at runtime replace all my custom attribute with
        [DataContract]

**Third**, to use some sort of pre-compile tool that will replace my attribute with [DataContract]

So if you have an idea how to implement any of these three (first and third preferred), or if you have an other idea it'll be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Whats wrong with current built in .NET serialization?

Comment: I want the serializetion attribute to be inherited,
[DataContract] is not inherited.

Comment: Of course DataContract is an inherited attribute. What it is not is inherit_able_

Comment: DataContractAttribute is a seald class, I can not inherit from it

Answer (score 0):

umm.... don't do that. just don't. trust me.

Mentor team members and use the framework as designed. You will get much more mileage.

word....

Comment: It's more then that.
i need to be able to change the mechanism reletivly easy,
starting to add\remove\replace all the entites attribute is just to comlicated and leave to mauch room for error, I rather hava one place withe realy nasty code that lots of places with not so pretty code.
Thats why if i could use my own attribute I could define it in own place, use it all over the code, and if I need to change it in the future i could go  specifcly to that class defintion, and not have to serch every singel attribute in the code...